# How to run PSql commands on remote server (or is there an alternative to psql?)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have a Postgres server, and an application running on a different server. The application is constantly loading new schemas into the postgres database from files, ie:

```
psql -h remoteserver.net -p 8888 -U postgres -d PropertyData -f %1
```

Needing to do this with psql adds the complexity of having to open up a terminal on the remote server and running a command, which I don't want since I don't know if we'll be running postgres on linux or windows.

1. Is there a way to do this load using a SQL command?
2. If not... (and I should probably break this out into a separate question), what is a good method to connect to a remote server (in c# .net) to run a terminal command (we'll assume windows for now).

Comment: The good thing with `psql` executable is it is avaiable for Windows & linux. That means you only have to set your Path correctly.
In any cases the C# method to run a new process is : `Process.Start` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do you recommend connecting to the remote server though? Process.Start is local.

Comment: Ow.... I thought you would be running the commands from a client sending them to the server (seeing `hostname` in the psql command and not `localhost` or no host at all).
IN the case in which your server is a Windows one (like you assumed) a simple WCF service listening for  a connection would be enough to start the process on the server.

Comment: The question is unclear because `psql -h hostname... -f scriptfile.sql` doesn't open a terminal on the remote server and doesn't care whether the remote is linux or windows.

Comment: When having a script containing a list of SQL commands, the main difficulty with not using `psql` is to separate the commands to send them one by one to the server. `psql` implements the logic to do that.

Comment: Yes, I can simply use psql as you suggest. It just requires I have the postgres tools installed on the application server as well as the database server. Sorry my question wasn't clear, I should not have put localhost.